# R import SDMX Data into a dataframe

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to download a SDMX data series from a website into a dataframe.
http://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DatasetCode=MEI_CLI

The SDMX DATA URL is:

http://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/MEI_CLI/LOLITOAA.AUS+AUT+BEL+CAN+CHL+CZE+DNK+EST+FIN+FRA+DEU+GRC+HUN+IRL+ISR+ITA+JPN+KOR+LUX+MEX+NLD+NZL+NOR+POL+PRT+SVK+SVN+ESP+SWE+CHE+TUR+GBR+USA+EA19+G4E+G-7+NAFTA+OECDE+OECD+ONM+A5M+BRA+CHN+IND+IDN+RUS+ZAF.M/all?startTime=2000-01&endTime=2015-05

I then tried:

```
library(XML2R)

file <- "http://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/MEI_CLI/LOLITOAA.AUS+AUT+BEL+CAN+CHL+CZE+DNK+EST+FIN+FRA+DEU+GRC+HUN+IRL+ISR+ITA+JPN+KOR+LUX+MEX+NLD+NZL+NOR+POL+PRT+SVK+SVN+ESP+SWE+CHE+TUR+GBR+USA+EA19+G4E+G-7+NAFTA+OECDE+OECD+ONM+A5M+BRA+CHN+IND+IDN+RUS+ZAF.M/all?startTime=2000-01&endTime=2015-05"

obs <- XML2Obs(file)
tables <- collapse_obs(obs)
```

How do I proceed now to collect the time, country and data value into a dataframe?

I also need to be able to collect data from 2000 (default setting is only two years)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the SDMX data source, you can use the [rsdmx](https://github.com/opensdmx/rsdmx/wiki) package (available on CRAN).

For this, you just need the following:

```
myURL <- "http://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/MEI_CLI/LOLITOAA.AUS+AUT+BEL+CAN+CHL+CZE+DNK+EST+FIN+FRA+DEU+GRC+HUN+IRL+ISR+ITA+JPN+KOR+LUX+MEX+NLD+NZL+NOR+POL+PRT+SVK+SVN+ESP+SWE+CHE+TUR+GBR+USA+EA19+G4E+G-7+NAFTA+OECDE+OECD+ONM+A5M+BRA+CHN+IND+IDN+RUS+ZAF.M/all?startTime=2013-06&endTime=2015-05"
sdmx.obj <- readSDMX(myURL)
sdmx.df <- as.data.frame(sdmx.obj)
head(sdmx.df)
```

And that's it! Feel free to check out the rsdmx wiki which contains more examples.

Answer (score 3):

Try `rvest` package with the original link:

```
library(rvest)
k1<-html("http://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DatasetCode=MEI_CLI")%>%
html_table(fill=TRUE,header=FALSE)%>%
.[[1]] //give me the first list only

View(k1) #see how table looks like. We only need row 4 (header), rows 8-last row.  
names(k1)<-k1[4,] #gives me header 

#We also don't need column 2. It's NA
data<-k1[8:nrow(k1),-2] #gives me final data 
rm(k1) # remove k1, not necessary now

head(data)
    Country Australia Austria Belgium Canada Chile Czech Republic Denmark Estonia Finland France Germany Greece Hungary Ireland Israel
8  Jun-2013      99.5    99.9    99.4   99.6 100.2           98.1    99.5    97.9    99.6   99.1   100.0   99.1    98.8   100.0  100.0
9  Jul-2013      99.5   100.0    99.6   99.7 100.1           98.4    99.7    98.2    99.8   99.2   100.2   99.0    98.7   100.1   99.9
10 Aug-2013      99.5   100.2    99.8   99.8 100.0           98.7   100.0    98.8    99.9   99.4   100.5   99.0    98.7   100.2   99.8
11 Sep-2013      99.6   100.3   100.1   99.9  99.9           99.2   100.2    99.4   100.0   99.6   100.7   99.0    98.7   100.2   99.7
12 Oct-2013      99.6   100.5   100.3  100.0  99.8           99.6   100.3    99.8   100.2   99.7   100.9   99.1    98.7   100.2   99.7
13 Nov-2013      99.7   100.6   100.5  100.0  99.7          100.0   100.4   100.0   100.4   99.8   101.0   99.3    98.6   100.2   99.6
   Italy Japan Korea Mexico Netherlands New Zealand Norway Poland Portugal Slovak Republic Slovenia Spain Sweden Switzerland Turkey
8   99.2 100.7 100.2   99.0        99.2       101.3  100.1   99.9     98.4            98.6     98.1  99.2   99.0       100.2  100.7
9   99.4 100.8 100.2   98.8        99.4       101.5  100.2  100.0     98.6            98.8     98.0  99.5   99.1       100.3  100.5
10  99.7 101.0 100.1   98.7        99.5       101.6  100.4  100.1     98.9            99.0     98.0  99.7   99.1       100.4  100.3
11  99.9 101.1 100.1   98.7        99.7       101.6  100.5  100.2     99.3            99.2     98.0 100.0   99.2       100.6  100.2
12 100.0 101.3 100.0   98.8        99.8       101.7  100.7  100.2     99.8            99.5     98.1 100.2   99.3       100.7  100.1
13 100.2 101.4 100.0   98.8        99.9       101.7  100.9  100.3    100.2            99.9     98.2 100.4   99.4       100.8   99.9
   United Kingdom United States Euro area (19 countries) Four Big European    G7 NAFTA OECD - Europe OECD - Total OECD + Major Six NME
8           100.2         100.4                     99.4              99.7 100.2 100.2          99.6        100.0                100.0
9           100.4         100.4                     99.6              99.9 100.3 100.2          99.8        100.1                100.0
10          100.6         100.4                     99.8             100.1 100.4 100.2         100.0        100.2                100.1
11          100.8         100.4                    100.0             100.3 100.5 100.2         100.1        100.3                100.1
12          100.9         100.4                    100.2             100.5 100.5 100.2         100.3        100.3                100.2
13          101.0         100.4                    100.4             100.6 100.6 100.2         100.4        100.4                100.2
   Major Five Asia Brazil China (People's Republic of) India Indonesia Russia South Africa
8            100.3   99.5                        100.5  99.0     100.4   99.1        100.6
9            100.3   99.4                        100.5  99.0     100.0   99.2        100.6
10           100.3   99.3                        100.5  98.9      99.5   99.3        100.6
11           100.2   99.3                        100.5  98.9      99.1   99.4        100.6
12           100.2   99.3                        100.4  98.8      98.9   99.6        100.5
13           100.2   99.3                        100.3  98.8      98.7   99.7        100.4
```

If you are willing to put extra effort to enter the header names, you can use `readHMTLTable` from XML package.

```
library(XML)
k2<-readHTMLTable("http://stats.oecd.o/Index.aspx?DatasetCode=MEI_CLI",header=FALSE) #first list gives the data
head(k2[[1]]) # as before you need to remove second column which is blank here

      V1 V2   V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11  V12   V13  V14  V15   V16   V17   V18   V19
1 Jun-2013    99.5  99.9  99.4  99.6 100.2  98.1  99.5  97.9  99.6 99.1 100.0 99.1 98.8 100.0 100.0  99.2 100.7
2 Jul-2013    99.5 100.0  99.6  99.7 100.1  98.4  99.7  98.2  99.8 99.2 100.2 99.0 98.7 100.1  99.9  99.4 100.8
3 Aug-2013    99.5 100.2  99.8  99.8 100.0  98.7 100.0  98.8  99.9 99.4 100.5 99.0 98.7 100.2  99.8  99.7 101.0
4 Sep-2013    99.6 100.3 100.1  99.9  99.9  99.2 100.2  99.4 100.0 99.6 100.7 99.0 98.7 100.2  99.7  99.9 101.1
5 Oct-2013    99.6 100.5 100.3 100.0  99.8  99.6 100.3  99.8 100.2 99.7 100.9 99.1 98.7 100.2  99.7 100.0 101.3
6 Nov-2013    99.7 100.6 100.5 100.0  99.7 100.0 100.4 100.0 100.4 99.8 101.0 99.3 98.6 100.2  99.6 100.2 101.4
    V20  V21  V22   V23   V24   V25   V26  V27  V28   V29  V30   V31   V32   V33   V34   V35   V36   V37   V38
1 100.2 99.0 99.2 101.3 100.1  99.9  98.4 98.6 98.1  99.2 99.0 100.2 100.7 100.2 100.4  99.4  99.7 100.2 100.2
2 100.2 98.8 99.4 101.5 100.2 100.0  98.6 98.8 98.0  99.5 99.1 100.3 100.5 100.4 100.4  99.6  99.9 100.3 100.2
3 100.1 98.7 99.5 101.6 100.4 100.1  98.9 99.0 98.0  99.7 99.1 100.4 100.3 100.6 100.4  99.8 100.1 100.4 100.2
4 100.1 98.7 99.7 101.6 100.5 100.2  99.3 99.2 98.0 100.0 99.2 100.6 100.2 100.8 100.4 100.0 100.3 100.5 100.2
5 100.0 98.8 99.8 101.7 100.7 100.2  99.8 99.5 98.1 100.2 99.3 100.7 100.1 100.9 100.4 100.2 100.5 100.5 100.2
6 100.0 98.8 99.9 101.7 100.9 100.3 100.2 99.9 98.2 100.4 99.4 100.8  99.9 101.0 100.4 100.4 100.6 100.6 100.2
    V39   V40   V41   V42  V43   V44  V45   V46  V47   V48
1  99.6 100.0 100.0 100.3 99.5 100.5 99.0 100.4 99.1 100.6
2  99.8 100.1 100.0 100.3 99.4 100.5 99.0 100.0 99.2 100.6
3 100.0 100.2 100.1 100.3 99.3 100.5 98.9  99.5 99.3 100.6
4 100.1 100.3 100.1 100.2 99.3 100.5 98.9  99.1 99.4 100.6
5 100.3 100.3 100.2 100.2 99.3 100.4 98.8  98.9 99.6 100.5
6 100.4 100.4 100.2 100.2 99.3 100.3 98.8  98.7 99.7 100.4
```

> 